# A tent shaped function and Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis

The question:

On the interval [−π, π] consider the function
$$f( x) \ =\ \begin{cases}
0 & if\ | x| \  >\ \delta \\
1-| x| /\delta  & if\ | x| \ \leqslant \ \delta 
\end{cases}$$
Thus the graph of f has the shape of a triangular tent. Show that
$$f( x ) =\frac{\delta }{2\pi } +2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1\ -\ cos( n\delta )}{\pi n^{2} \delta } \ cos( x )$$

My attempts:

Since the function in question is even,
I thought that this would be sufficient to find only cos coefficients.
I decided to obtain the coefficients integrating the interval [-,] as follows

$B_{n} \ =\ \frac{1}{\pi }\int _{( -\pi )}^{\pi } f( x) \ cos( nx) \ dx$

giving that ||<

$$ \begin{array}{l}
\frac{1}{\pi }\int _{( -\pi )}^{\pi } f( x) \ cos( nx) \ dx\ \\
=\frac{1}{\pi }\left( \ \int _{( -\delta )}^{0}( 1+x/\delta ) cos( nx) \ dx+\int _{0}^{\delta }( 1-x/\delta ) cos( nx) \ dx\ \right)\\
\\
=\frac{1\ -\ cos( n\delta )}{\pi n^{2} \delta }
\end{array}$$

Then I thought that maybe the sine coefficients would
eventually turn into a vertical constant offset.
but they end up being zero, which is pretty obvious since the function is even.
How can I get this constant $\frac{\delta }{2\pi }$?

Comment: The Fourier expansion consists of $\cos$ terms, $\sin$ terms (which are zero), and *a constant term* $B_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx$.

Comment: @JohnBarber aah, yes, I forgot about that, thank you